# How to make console app Check if process is running

Tags: vb.net

i'm making a Visual basic Console App to inject a DLL to an  exe process if the process is running 
the question here is how to make console application checks if the desired process is running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Process` class provides methods that allow you to get lists of running processes.  For instance:

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length <> 0 Then
    ' Notepad is running
End If
```

Comment: what is if i want to see a list of application like from a dictionary or something.??

Comment: @Fahid Sounds like a great idea for a new question :)  'Process.GetProcesses' returns an array of 'Process' objects, one per running process on the current machine. That should have all the info you need to build a dictionary, if that's what you need.

Comment: Why don't we explore little more on this subject? I will start a new thread and will share the link with you soon. Thanks ;)